# THREE.js: DragControls.js - horiontally

Tags: javascript, three.js, drag-and-drop

When trying to modify the "webgl_interactive_draggablecubes" (https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes), I was not able to drag the items horizontally. If I understand,

```
_plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint( _camera.getWorldDirection( _plane.normal ), object.position );
```

It makes the _plane face camera located in the object.position. So, among the things I have tried was:

```
_plane.position.copy(object.position.makeRotationX( -Math.PI / 2));
```

But I always get a: TypeError: _plane.position is undefined.

How would you do that?
The original DragControls.js can be found [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js) and lines 92 and 207 are of great interest.

Thanks for the ones brave enough to try to help me! Hooray to you!

Comment: Because [`THREE.Plane()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Plane) doesn't have `.position` property.

Comment: Ok, I could add a real transparent mesh and make it disappear as I did before but the _plane.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint() create a reference to draw an intersection without creating a mesh. Right? If so, my question is how to do the same horizontally (not facing the camera)?

Comment: Alternatively, see https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to look at this to see if I can find an answer.